# How to run async bash command in java?

Tags: java, bash, asynchronous, concurrency, execution

I'm trying to run an async bash command from a java file and wait for it to finish before I continue the java code execution.

At this moment I've tried using `Callable` like so:

```java
class AsyncBashCmds implements Callable{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        try {
            String[] cmd = { "grep", "-ir", "<" , "."};

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); 

            return "true"; // need to hold this before the execution is completed.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "false";
        }
    }
}
```

and I call it like so:

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<String> future =  executorService.submit(new runCPPinShell(hookResponse));
String isFinishedRunningScript = future.get();
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's going wrong: you say that you are trying the command. But you don't say what's going wrong? DOes (it appear that) nothing happens at all? Do you get an error message/code? Does the bash command run but do the wrong thing?

Comment: Code formating, tags added

Comment: the command is executed but the java code does not wait for it to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way is to use Java 9+ `.onExit()`:

```
private static CompletableFuture<String> runCmd(String... args) {
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args)
            .onExit().thenApply(pr -> "true");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("false");
    }
}
```

```
Future<String> future = runCmd("grep", "-ir", "<" , ".");
String isFinishedRunningScript = future.get(); // Note - THIS will block.
```

If you want to block anyway, use `.waitFor()`.

Comment: I get this error : `cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method onExit()
  location: class java.lang.Process` I assume I do not use Java 9+ ?

Comment: I am not running Java 9+ but `.waitFor()` solved it for me,  Thanks!